# How to solve: Conflicting changes detected. This may happen when trying to insert multiple entities with the same key

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, unit-of-work

My problem is inserting `memberCommits` into SQL database. The error is that this may happen when trying to insert multiple entities with the same key. I tried to check the ids of `memberCommits` are duplicates, but they're not.

First, I'm going to check if the member already exists. If not I'm going to add it, and then after that I will add the `memberCommit`. First commit is okay, but after that the error shows.

```
var member = this.unitOfWork.Repository<Member>().Queryable().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == memberMetric.Name && x.Class.Id == @class.Id);
var isMemberExisting = false;
if (member == null)
{
    member = new Member()
    {
        Class = @class,
        Name = memberMetric.Name,
        ObjectState = ObjectState.Added
    };
}
else
{
    isMemberExisting = true;
}
if (!isMemberExisting)
{
    @class.Members.Add(member);
}

var memberCommit = new MemberCommit()
{
    Member = member,
    Commit = commit,
    ClassCoupling = memberMetric.ClassCouplings.Count(),
    CyclomaticComplexity = memberMetric.CyclomaticComplexity,
    LinesOfCode = memberMetric.LinesOfCode,
    MaintainabilityIndex = memberMetric.MaintainabilityIndex,

    //  Please double check the CodeFile,
    CodeFile = memberMetric.CodeFile,
    HalsteadBugs = memberMetric.GetHalsteadMetrics().GetBugs(),
    HalsteadDifficulty = memberMetric.GetHalsteadMetrics().GetDifficulty(),
    HalsteadEffort = memberMetric.GetHalsteadMetrics().GetEffort().TotalDays,
    HalsteadLength = memberMetric.GetHalsteadMetrics().GetLength(),
    HalsteadVocabulary = memberMetric.GetHalsteadMetrics().GetVocabulary(),
    HalsteadVolume = memberMetric.GetHalsteadMetrics().GetVolume(),
    UniqueOperands = memberMetric.GetHalsteadMetrics().NumberOfUniqueOperands,
    UniqueOperators = memberMetric.GetHalsteadMetrics().NumberOfUniqueOperators,
    Operands = memberMetric.GetHalsteadMetrics().NumberOfOperands,
    Operators = memberMetric.GetHalsteadMetrics().NumberOfOperators,

    ObjectState = ObjectState.Added
};

member.MemberCommits.Add(memberCommit);

return member;
```